# Flowplayer Video Progress Tracking?

Tags: video, tracking, flowplayer

Using the FlowPlayer API, is there a way to capture Video Progress? I'm looking to capture the progress of the video so I can fire events to the page at certain points in the Video. In Flash, there is Progress Event that fires every frame, and I was hoping that since FlowPlayer is Flash, that the Progress Event would also be exposed. I can't seem to find anything as straight-forward in the FlowPlayer docs.

If a Progress Event doesn't exist. Are there any suggestions on how to construct a such a thing using JS setInterval and existing FlowPlayer API methods?

Comment: I was able to devise a method using cuepoints. My particular problem was that I needed to dynamically determine when the video had been played 25, 50 an 75% of the way through. The earliest I found the video duration is known to the player is in the onMetaData event. This worked for me:

Comment: This worked* for me:
https://gist.github.com/1161365


*It doesn't work on iOS when using the FP iPad plugin. But that seems to be a bigger FlowPlayer issue.

Answer (score 7):

I hacked up a quick snippet of Javascript that interacts with the Flowplayer `Player` and `Clip` objects to determine the video progress.

```
var videoProgressInterval;

flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf");
flowplayer("player").onStart(startVideoProgressChecking);
flowplayer("player").onResume(startVideoProgressChecking);
flowplayer("player").onStop(stopVideoProgressChecking);
flowplayer("player").onPause(stopVideoProgressChecking);
flowplayer("player").onFinish(stopVideoProgressChecking);

function startVideoProgressChecking() {
    videoProgressInterval = setInterval(checkVideoProgress, 1000);
    videoProgressInterval();
}

function stopVideoProgressChecking() {
    clearInterval(videoProgressInterval);  
}

function checkVideoProgress() {
    var time_completed = flowplayer("player").getTime();
    var total_time = flowplayer("player").getClip().fullDuration;
    var percent_done = Math.floor((time_completed / total_time) * 100);

    console.log(percent_done + "% of video done");
}
```

You can see a demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qnxM/).

It registers event handles for the `start` and `resume` events of the player. Once video playback has begun, it registers an interval which runs every second (feel free to modify this to run more often). The interval calls `checkVideoProgress()` every time it gets executed which then gets the current playback time and total duration from the `Clip` object to calculate the progress.

Additionally, an event handler is also registered for `stop`, `pause` and `finish` events to clear the interval once the video has been paused/stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Flowplayers [Cuepoints](https://flowplayer.org/docs/cuepoints.html)

Add cuepoints to the data property (either seconds, or seconds from end with a minus)

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-cuepoints="[1.5, 2, 3, -1]"><!-- video here --></div>
```

Then bind an event:

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) {
    api.bind("cuepoint", function (e, api, cuepoint) {
       console.log(cuepoint);
    });
});
```